# How to log the state of a process with camunda?

Tags: java, business-process-management, bpmn, camunda

How to log the state and the run of a process with camunda ? Something like a historic of actions.

I use Camunda 7.1.0 build with maven on Tomcat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want to retrieve that kind of information programmatically. From the ProcessEngine you can retrieve the historyService and create a query for "ActivityInstances", e.g. like

```
processEngine.getHistoryService().createHistoricActivityInstanceQuery()
.processDefinitionId("myProcess").processInstanceId(pid).orderByHistoricActivityInstanceStartTime().list();
```

Make sure that the history level of the engine is set at least to level "activity". Otherwise you will just see currently active ActivityInstances, but no historic ones.